# Can I pass my search box values as parameters in my function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have objects for each team containing arrays of numbers inside of them

*an example team(really setting an example atm, just look at all those 
    goals scored)*

```
luton = {

    name: "Luton Town",
    link: "luton",
    league: "League 1",
    homeGoalsScored: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 2, 2, 0, 4, 3],
    homeGoalsConceded: [1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],

    awayGoalsScored: [0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    awayGoalsConceded: [1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0],

    totalGoalsScored: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 0, 
    5, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 3],
    totalGoalsConceded: [1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2],

},
```

when I type the two teams names as parameters in the coefficient function in the console then it works exactly how I want it to.

I would like the user to be able to type the two teams into search boxes and on enter run the function but I can't seem to pass the two values into the function.

I will need to change the search to actually grab the link from the object below, but for now I just want it to function so I am typing the teams exactly as the object is named.

My first project so any guidance would be helpful

I've tried to use the searchbox.value as shown in the showteams function and have tried using JSON.parse methods aswell as `${awayTeam}` but I'm not 100% sure what they are doing, please find my script (- the teams and their stats) below

```
const awayGoalsBox = document.getElementById('away-gs');
const awayGoalsConcededBox = document.getElementById('away-gc');

const homeGoalsBox = document.getElementById('home-gs');
const homeGoalsConcededBox = document.getElementById('home-gc');

const arrAvg = (arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length); 

function applyGoals(stat, box) {
    var filled = (`${stat}`);
    box.innerHTML = filled;
};

function home(team) {
    var avgHomeGoalsLong = arrAvg(team.homeGoalsScored);
    var avgHomeGoals = avgHomeGoalsLong.toFixed(2);
    applyGoals(avgHomeGoals, homeGoalsBox);

    var avgHomeGoalsConcededLong = arrAvg(team.homeGoalsConceded);
    var avgHomeGoalsConceded = avgHomeGoalsConcededLong.toFixed(2);
    applyGoals(avgHomeGoalsConceded, homeGoalsConcededBox);
};

function away(team) {
    var avgAwayGoalsLong = arrAvg(team.awayGoalsScored);
    var avgAwayGoals = avgAwayGoalsLong.toFixed(2);
    applyGoals(avgAwayGoals, awayGoalsBox);

    var avgAwayGoalsConcededLong = arrAvg(team.awayGoalsConceded);
    var avgAwayGoalsConceded = avgAwayGoalsConcededLong.toFixed(2);
    applyGoals(avgAwayGoalsConceded, awayGoalsConcededBox);
};

function coefficient(homeTeam, awayTeam) {

    var avgHomeGoals = arrAvg(homeTeam.homeGoalsScored);
    var avgHomeGoalsConceded = arrAvg(homeTeam.homeGoalsConceded);

    var avgAwayGoals = arrAvg(awayTeam.awayGoalsScored);
    var avgAwayGoalsConceded = arrAvg(awayTeam.awayGoalsConceded);

    var i = (avgAwayGoals - avgHomeGoals);
    var j = (avgHomeGoalsConceded - avgAwayGoalsConceded);

    if (avgAwayGoalsConceded <= 0.5) {
        q = .5
    } else if (avgAwayGoalsConceded <= 1) {
        q = .4
    } else if (avgAwayGoalsConceded <= 1.5) {
        q = .3
    } else if (avgAwayGoalsConceded <= 2) {
        q = .2
    } else if (avgAwayGoalsConceded <= 2.5) {
        q = .1
    } else {
        q = 0
    };

    if (avgHomeGoalsConceded <= 0.5) {
        u = -.5
    } else if (avgHomeGoalsConceded <= 1) {
        u = -.4
    } else if (avgHomeGoalsConceded <= 1.5) {
        u = -.3
    } else if (avgHomeGoalsConceded <= 2) {
        u = -.2
    } else if (avgHomeGoalsConceded <= 2.5) {
        u = -.1
    } else {
        u = 0
    };

    if (avgAwayGoals <= 0.5) {
        y = 0
    } else if (avgAwayGoals <= 1) {
        y = .1
    } else if (avgAwayGoals <= 1.5) {
        y = .2
    } else if (avgAwayGoals <= 2) {
        y = .3
    } else if (avgAwayGoals <= 2.5) {
        y = .4
    } else {
        y = .5
    };    

    if (avgHomeGoals <= 0.5) {
        cc = 0
    } else if (avgHomeGoals <= 1) {
        cc = -.1
    } else if (avgHomeGoals <= 1.5) {
        cc = -.2
    } else if (avgHomeGoals <= 2) {
        cc = -.3
    } else if (avgHomeGoals <= 2.5) {
        cc = -.4
    } else {
        cc = -.5
    };

    var sum = (i + j + q + u + y + cc);

    away(awayTeam);
    home(homeTeam);

    var awaybox = document.querySelector(`#away`);
    var homebox = document.querySelector(`#home`);

    document.getElementById('name-away').innerHTML = awayTeam.name;
    document.getElementById('name-home').innerHTML = homeTeam.name;

    var sumNum = parseFloat(sum);
    var coeff = (sumNum / 5);   
    document.getElementById('coefficient').innerHTML = coeff.toFixed(2);
};

const homeSearch = document.querySelector('#home-search');
const awaySearch = document.querySelector('#away-search');
const submit = document.querySelector('#submit');

function showteams(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var homeTeam = homeSearch.value;
    var awayTeam = awaySearch.value;

    coefficient(homeTeam, awayTeam);
};

submit.addEventListener('click', showteams);
```

when I type coefficient(homeTeam, awayTeam) into the console it does the statistics and prints them in their corresponding boxes but when I use search it comes up with

```
script.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
    at arrAvg (script.js:5)
    at coefficient (script.js:208)
    at HTMLInputElement.showteam (script.js:1524)
```

at request, here is my html

```
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <header class="grid">
            <h1>betMarco</h1>
        </header>

    <div class="stats-box home" id="home">
        <h3 class="heading">HOME</h3>
        <form class="add-items">
            <input type="text" name="team" class="home-search" id="home- 
             search" placeholder="Home Team" value=" " required>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
        </form>

        <div class="values name">
            <p id="name-home"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="values goals-scored">
            <h6>HGS PG:</h6>
            <p id="home-gs"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="values goals-conceded">
            <h6>HGC PG:</h6>
            <p id="home-gc"></p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="stats-box away" id="away">
        <h3 class="heading">AWAY</h3>
        <form class="search-items">
                <input type="text" name="team" class="away-search"  
                 id="away-search" placeholder="Away Team" value=" ">
        </form>

        <div class="values name">
            <p id="name-away"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="values goals-scored">
            <h6>AGS PG:</h6>
            <p id="away-gs"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="values goals-conceded">
            <h6>AGC PG:</h6>
            <p id="away-gc"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there additional code not included at the question?

Comment: Yes, but theres quite alot so i tried to get just an important snippet

Comment: Given that you are interacting with html, may you show it (or at least part of it)? The error that you are getting means that the team.awayGoalsScored from team passed to away function is undefined. Or it has never been set or you lost it value before calling the function. If it was once set you may have lost the value at: `*this does a bunch of stuff that gives a final score and show it on 
screen*`. You would have to give us more code to help but one tip that I can give in advance is to place some console.log's and see what values you are getting on the way. Regards.

Comment: added some more in for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, it was just using a string and not the object, instead I found if I matched the string to one of the objects in the array of teams then I could grab the object and submit that which is where all the data is. Not sure if it's the most efficient way but it works

```
function showTeams(e) {
e.preventDefault();

let homeTeam = '';
let awayTeam = '';

if (premiership.find(o => o.name == homeSearch.value) || premiership.find(o => o.link == homeSearch.value)) {
    homeTeam = premiership.find(o => o.name == homeSearch.value) || premiership.find(o => o.link == homeSearch.value)
} else if (championship.find(o => o.name == homeSearch.value) || championship.find(o => o.link == homeSearch.value)) {
    homeTeam = championship.find(o => o.name == homeSearch.value) || championship.find(o => o.link == homeSearch.value)
} else if (leagueOne.find(o => o.name == homeSearch.value) || leagueOne.find(o => o.link == homeSearch.value)) {
    homeTeam = leagueOne.find(o => o.name == homeSearch.value) || leagueOne.find(o => o.link == homeSearch.value)
} else if (leagueTwo.find(o => o.name == homeSearch.value) || leagueTwo.find(o => o.link == homeSearch.value)) {
    homeTeam = leagueTwo.find(o => o.name == homeSearch.value) || leagueTwo.find(o => o.link == homeSearch.value)
};

if (premiership.find(o => o.name == awaySearch.value) || premiership.find(o => o.link == awaySearch.value)) {
    awayTeam = premiership.find(o => o.name == awaySearch.value) || premiership.find(o => o.link == awaySearch.value)
} else if (championship.find(o => o.name == awaySearch.value) || championship.find(o => o.link == awaySearch.value)) {
    awayTeam = championship.find(o => o.name == awaySearch.value) || championship.find(o => o.link == awaySearch.value)
} else if (leagueOne.find(o => o.name == awaySearch.value) || leagueOne.find(o => o.link == awaySearch.value)) {
    awayTeam = leagueOne.find(o => o.name == awaySearch.value) || leagueOne.find(o => o.link == awaySearch.value)
} else if (leagueTwo.find(o => o.name == awaySearch.value) || leagueTwo.find(o => o.link == awaySearch.value)) {
    awayTeam = leagueTwo.find(o => o.name == awaySearch.value) || leagueTwo.find(o => o.link == awaySearch.value)
};

coefficient(homeTeam, awayTeam)
};
```